# ScrollView with bottom transition is giving weird behavior?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

Just copy and paste the code to see the behavior. I want to confirm if I am doing something wrong or is this a bug?

```
import SwiftUI

struct StackOverflow13: View {
    @State var hide: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                self.hide.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Hide")
            }
            Spacer()

            if(!hide) {
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(1...20, id:\.self) {
                            Text("\($0)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 50, alignment: .center)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
                .animation(.linear)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }

        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct StackOverflow13_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StackOverflow13()
    }
}
```

Upon running the code and pressing `Hide` numbers will start shaking infinitely, if I remove the `.transition` modifier everything seems to work fine.

Also it's important to note removing `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea` modifier would solve it, but I do need this modifier.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same shaking behaviour with your code on iPhones(10 to 11) but not on older iPhones and ipads. But if I use

```
.frame(height: 70, alignment: .center)
```

The shaking disappears. My guess is that there is not enough space to render/layout the ScrollView with height=50 on certain devices/resolutions.

Using macos 10.15.5, Xcode 11.5 and 11.6 beta, target ios 13.5 and mac catalyst. Tested on real device iPhone and iPad, and various but not all simulators.

Comment: Yup I see same behavior with different screen sizes, I will file a bug report with Apple. Thank you for your effort.